# Outlook/Exchange - Changing display of "From" user

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook

This has been plaguing me for awhile.  I am using Outlook 2013 with my own Exchange Server.

When I receive an email from a contact, it is displayed in the way prescribed by *their* mail server.  So if someone sets their username to "smith, JohNny", then this is what I see in my inbox.

I would like to make it so that when I receive an email, Outlook attempts to display the email using the "Display As" field of a contact saved in my contacts folder.

The one workaround that I have found is to create a "Contact" in exchange and add the person's email and proper display name.  This seems to work flawlessly, but it does not help for my email accounts where I do not have admin control over Exchange (such as my work email).

What is the best solution here?  This seems like it should be the default behavior of Outlook -

Comment: Why do you want this? This is an odd request

Comment: `This seems like it should be the default behavior of Outlook` - Why? Because you want it to be the default behavior?

Comment: @ewwhite - Alot of people emailing me have all sorts of naming methodologies - some email me regularly from multiple accounts, each using a different format.  For instance, my Dad's gmail comes in as "Panda Bear" and his work email appears as "Last, First".  I have him (and everyone else) as "First Last" and it would be nice to be able to easily sort and see all of the email from this one contact.

Comment: @joeqwerty - When you create a contact, one of the fields that you can populate is "Display as". However, this only works when you are sending an email that you are creating. When you receive an email from that contact, or (by default) when you are replying to an email received by that contact, the "Display as" field in the contact is completely ignored

Comment: So you want the ability to sort by email address rather than display name? http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm

Comment: @HBruijn - no, I want to sort by the person that has sent the email.  For instance, if someone that I communicate with has two emails: john.smith@gmail.com and js@coolfirm.com - I want to be able to have both of those emails in a contact and then have outlook recognize that that contact is the person from whom the email originated.